# Flutter TextStyle (not TextTheme) difference between apply() and copyWith()

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-theme, textstyle

I'm creating theme for my app.

I'm confusing these 2 methods (apply, copyWith) of TextStyle.
What should be used?

There're also 2 methods with the same names in TextTheme.
I understand them, but can not get the idea in TextStyle.

Logic of these 2 in TextStyle is different than in TextTheme

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at the docs it shows that `apply` uses default values for some parameters if you don't specify them.

> TextStyle apply(
> {Color? color,
> Color? backgroundColor,
> TextDecoration? decoration,
> Color? decorationColor,
> TextDecorationStyle? decorationStyle,
> double decorationThicknessFactor = 1.0,
> double decorationThicknessDelta = 0.0,
> String? fontFamily,
> List? fontFamilyFallback,
> double fontSizeFactor = 1.0,
> double fontSizeDelta = 0.0,
> int fontWeightDelta = 0,
> FontStyle? fontStyle,
> double letterSpacingFactor = 1.0,
> double letterSpacingDelta = 0.0,
> double wordSpacingFactor = 1.0,
> double wordSpacingDelta = 0.0,
> double heightFactor = 1.0,
> double heightDelta = 0.0,
> TextBaseline? textBaseline,
> TextLeadingDistribution? leadingDistribution,
> Locale? locale,
> List? shadows,
> List? fontFeatures}
> )

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/apply.html

`copywith` does not use default values and uses (copies) the values already defined in the original TextStyle object.

> TextStyle copyWith(
> {bool? inherit,
> Color? color,
> Color? backgroundColor,
> String? fontFamily,
> List? fontFamilyFallback,
> double? fontSize,
> FontWeight? fontWeight,
> FontStyle? fontStyle,
> double? letterSpacing,
> double? wordSpacing,
> TextBaseline? textBaseline,
> double? height,
> TextLeadingDistribution? leadingDistribution,
> Locale? locale,
> Paint? foreground,
> Paint? background,
> List? shadows,
> List? fontFeatures,
> TextDecoration? decoration,
> Color? decorationColor,
> TextDecorationStyle? decorationStyle,
> double? decorationThickness,
> String? debugLabel}
> )

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/copyWith.html

Edit:
It also seems that they have different parameters, for example `apply` doesn't have `fontSize` and `fontWeight` as a parameter.

Comment: I'm still not sure the use case for each one.

Comment: ah ok, I get the idea. Thank you.

Comment: just to make things clear, you saying that `apply` replaces all properties not provided with the default one, means not from the object ? if that so, then what's the point ? isn't this equivalent of creating a new object ???

Comment: @OverLoadedBurden `apply` uses the default values if those are not provided. Not all of them have default values. `copy` uses either the newly provided parameters or the already existing ones. I encourage you to take a look at the implementation in the doc links. They will make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

apply() creates a copy of text style replacing **all** the specified properties in it.

copyWith()creates a copy of text style, but it only replaces the given values with new values